# Averaging of the digital data

Tags: bash, loops

I have a log file consisted title and number of relevant strings consisted of digital data

```
This is the benchmarks ns/day for wsp systems
21.473
21.483
21.425
21.548
21.588
21.587
21.522
21.547
21.549
21.487
```

Within the log I need to automatically add last line consisted of AVERAGE = and to calculate averaged value from the digits on 2-11 strings. Will be very thankful for elegant bash script which will open the log, looping the strings and add average within it last string!

Thx!

James

Comment: `awk 'NR>=2{sum+=$0}1;END{print "AVERAGE=" (sum/(NR-1))}' input.log`

Answer (score 0):

This awk one-liner should work for you:

```
awk '7;NR>1{t+=$0}END{printf "EVERAGE=%.3f\n",t/(NR-1)}' file
```

What it does:

- read a line and print as it is
- if line number >1, sum the value, and save to var `t`
- after printing the last line in file out, calculate the average, and print in same format as other numbers. (`printf` function)

if you test it on your example file, it gives:

```
kent$  awk '7;NR>1{t+=$0}END{printf "AVERAGE=%.3f\n",t/(NR-1)}' f
this is the benchmarks ns/day for wsp systems
21.473
21.483
21.425
21.548
21.588
21.587
21.522
21.547
21.549
21.487
AVERAGE=21.521
```

Comment: it soound good. btw how is possible to print only average value7 At the end I need only to put AVERAGE within existing log at the bottom so if I provie at the end of AFK  >> ${HOME}/final_bench_${tit}.log it will copy initial information within the same log =)

Comment: non-zero number will do default action in awk. 7, 1, 100 are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would use awk for this

```
awk '{sum+=$1; print} END{print "AVERAGE=" sum/(NR-1)}' logfile
```

`sum+=$1` will take add the first element of each string onto a variable

The `END` statement will do the average based on the number of line (or 'record' in awk vocabulary) `NR`